How to access the header in the subsequent splits in Apache Camel
I need to stream a file and process the lines one by line.
During this process, I need to keep track of the successful processed lines and failed process lines and publish those metrics for each split.
Camel split will create new exchange on each split so the headers will be lost and also the aggregation will not work here. Since the results will be accessed at the end of the split.
How to resolve this problem using camel?
Sample route:
    onException(Exception.class)
        .handled(true)
        .process(new FailureProcessor()) // increment failureCount
        .to("{{publishMetrics}}");

    from("{{file}}")
        .setHeader("successCount", constant(0))
        .setHeader("failureCount", constant(0))
        .split(body().tokenize("\n"))
        .process(new MyProcessor()) // Process the lines
        .process(new SuccessProcessor()) // Increment the successCount header
        .to("{{publishMetrics}}") // Publish the metrics(successCount & failureCount)
        .end()
        .end(); // split ends


You can use a custom aggregation strategy to combine the results of your split into a single summary message which you could then publish.
See https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/eips/split-eip.html#_aggregating

I want to publish the results on each split. Aggregation will not work here, since the results of aggregation will be accessed at the end of all the splits which I don't want for my usecase.

From memory, headers are copied to the new exchanges by the split. If you use some object, like AtomicInteger, as your header value then the copy of the header in each exchange will refer to the same AtomicInteger  - so incrementing it within the split will do what you want.
